# Segmentation fault using SDL with C++, trying to Blit images

Tags: c++, sdl

OK - I have an interesting one here.  I'm working on a tetris clone (basically to "level-up" my skills).  I was trying to refactor my code to get it abstracted the way I wanted it.  While it was working just fine before, now I get a segmentation fault before any images can be blitted.  I've tried debugging it to no avail.

I have posted my SVN working copy of the project [here](http://www.andrews.edu/~sajo/downloads/Tetris-clone.tar.gz).

It's just a small project and someone with more knowledge than me and a good debugger will probably figure it out in a snap.  The only dependency is [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org).   Kudos to the person that can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:  As far as I can tell, what I have now and what I had before are logically the same, so I wouldn't think that what I have now would cause a segmentation fault.  Just run an svn revert on the working copy, recompile and you can see that it was working...

Comment: You should probably post a stack trace, either from a core file or from running it in a debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, the original link to the working copy is not available (my alma mater is cool and apparently deletes tarballs like that).  I'll see if I can find a copy of the code on one of my old hard drives and get a more permanent link set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at line 15 to 18 of Surface.cpp:

```
    surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( tempSurface );
    surface = tempSurface;
}
SDL_FreeSurface( tempSurface );
```

I assume it segfaults because when you use this surface later, you are actually operating on tempSurface because of this line:

```
surface = tempSurface;
```

and not the surface returned by SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(). Since you free tempSurface, surface is now pointing to invalid memory. To fix, simply remove the second line in the else block.

Comment: doh!  I had a feeling it was something simple...  The next question is:  what in the world impressed me to do that? :P

Comment: Oh wait - i remember now - i was getting rid of SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha entirely to see if that was the problem.  Then I forgot to get rid of that line when I put SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha back in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SDL installed on my machine, but after looking through the code.

I noticed this in the Output.cpp file:

```
display = new Surface();
```

You do nothing. The constructor for this is empty. (surface is not initialized).

Then in Output::initalize() you do:

```
display->surface = SDL_SetVideoMode( 800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF );
```

This looks like the issue Surface::surface was never actually initialized. If you haven't found the solution, when i get home i'll digg into it.

Comment: That should be fine, because SDL_SetVideoMode(...) will create and initialize the screen surface and then pass the pointer back to display->surface

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, a segmentation fault happens when you are trying to mnaipulate a ponter which is no longer available, or you are trying to change a constant's value.