# Problem with SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha (c++)

Tags: c++, sdl, alpha-transparency

As I stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341192/segmentation-fault-using-sdl-with-c-trying-to-blit-images), I am using SDL for a small game I'm developing.  Now I am having problems with SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha.  I am trying to create a surface with an alpha channel from a PNG image.  It was working before, but now that I've done some slight refactoring something got broken.  I've narrowed it down to this constructor:

```
Surface::Surface( tfilename file ) {
    // initialize the surface data member to the image indicated by filename
    SDL_Surface *tempSurface;
    tempSurface = IMG_Load( file.c_str() );
    if ( !tempSurface ) {
        surface = NULL;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( tempSurface );
        //surface = tempSurface;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface( tempSurface );
}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I run it I get a Segmentation fault.
The error reported by gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb79c16c0 (LWP 8089)]
0xb7e8b9a3 in SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
#0  0xb7e8b9a3 in SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#1  0x0804987e in Surface (this=0x804d060, file=@0xbfb20760) at Surface.cpp:16
#2  0x0804a159 in Image (this=0x804d038, x=0, y=0, file=@0xbfb207a0)
    at Image.cpp:16
#3  0x0804a3de in Object (this=0x804d028, imageFile=@0xbfb207dc)
    at Object.cpp:4
#4  0x080491cb in Application (this=0xbfb20810) at Application.cpp:8
#5  0x08048e0d in main () at main.cpp:5
```

If I comment out `surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( tempSurface );`  and `SDL_FreeSurface( tempSurface );` and uncomment `surface = tempSurface;` like so:

```
Surface::Surface( tfilename file ) {
    // initialize the surface data member to the image indicated by filename
    SDL_Surface *tempSurface;
    tempSurface = IMG_Load( file.c_str() );
    if ( !tempSurface ) {
        surface = NULL;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        //surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( tempSurface );
        surface = tempSurface;
    }
    //SDL_FreeSurface( tempSurface );
}
```

Then it seems to work just fine.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?  Actually, the transparency seems to work, too when I comment out SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha.  Is that function only meant to be used with images that do not already have an alpha channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMG_Load should handle transparent PNG's automatically, as the end of your post notes. What is the actual exception/error being thrown? Your stack trace doesn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the link here (related function):

[SDL_DisplayFormat](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat)

"You have to call SDL_Init before using the SDL_DisplayFormat function. If you don't, your program will crash with an access violation."

Could that be your problem?